# Which of these lines is more efficient (CPU/memory-wise) when executed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance, memory-management

I have two scenerios. In each scenerio, tell me which version of doing the same exact thing is more efficient (e.g. uses less CPU or memory):

First scenerio:

```
/*version 1*/
    $('body').append('#something');
/*version 2*/
    $('#something').insertAfter('body > *:last-child');
```

Second scenerio:

```
/*version 1*/
    $('#something').method1();
    $('#something').method2();
    $('#something').method3();
/*version 2*/
    var $reference = $('#something');
    $reference.method1();
    $reference.method2();
    $reference.method3();
```

So in each scenerio, which version is more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first scenario the first is more efficent since `$("#someid")` ultimatly amounts to a `document.getElementById` call which is a call to native code. Id selectors are fairly cheap compared to class selectors. A call to `$('body > *:last-child')` is going to going to be a much more complex call to SizzleJS.

In the second scenario the second is more efficient since you avoid making an additional two calls to `document.getElementById` and just declare your object up front.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but...

In the grand scheme of things, the difference is going to be so barely measurable that it doesn't really matter.  Just focus on writing clean, simple and easily maintainable code.

Comment: I know this already, but knowing what is more efficient from the get go is still better than not knowing at all, no matter how small the benefits are. If 1000 employees are aware of the small efficiency gains, then 1000 small things can be big.

Comment: Microsoft developers are sooner to right neater code, and leave three lines of comments for each line of code.  :)  But seriously, this answer may help others who are stuck on such nuances more than you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#something').method1().method2().method3();
```

unless you plan to reuse the object, then do

```
var $ref = $('#ref');
$ref.method1().method2().method3();
```

Comment: what if method1(), method2(), method3() don't return the object?

Comment: chaining is part of the benefit of using jquery.  is your comment assuming that the user is extending the jquery object with other functionality?

Comment: I was assuming jquery methods. Thanks!